# Add different animate.css class to different divs via a single jquery statement

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie to jquery (and programming).

I have various divs on one page, to each of which I want to add a different effect from animate.css. Is there a way of doing this within a single statement. For example, something like:

```
$(function(){

    $('.class1, .class2, .class3').addClass('effect1 animated', 'effect2 animated', 'effect3 animated');

});
```

or will I have to assign it in this way:

```
$(function(){

    $('.class1').addClass('effect1 animated');
    $('.class2').addClass('effect2 animated');
    $('.class3').addClass('effect3 animated');

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the addClass() that takes a callback

```js
$(function() {
  var names = ['effect1', 'effect2', 'effect3']
  $('.class1, .class2, .class3').addClass(function(i, clazz) {
    return names[i] + ' animated'
  })
});
```

```css
.effect1 {
  color: red;
}
.effect2 {
  color: green;
}
.effect3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">1</div>
<div class="class2">2</div>
<div class="class3">3</div>
```

Comment: Arun, thanks for the answer! But, the effects have names like "fadeInDown", "BounceIn", "BounceOut"...The effects are not named sequentially.
Thanks!

Comment: @Yadu have a look at the udpate

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, you can add one more class with class1, class2 .... like 'my-class'

```js
var elements = $(document).find('.my-class');
$.each(elements, function(index, element){
    var classAtr= $(this).attr('class');
  classes = classAtr.split(" ");
  var index = classes[1].substring(5,6);  $(this).addClass("effect" + index + " animated");
});
```

```css
.effect1{
  color : red;
}
.effect2{
  color : orange;
}
.effect3{
  color : green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <li class="my-class class1">1</li>
    <li class="my-class class2">2</li>
    <li class="my-class class3">3</li>
</body>
```

http://jsbin.com/tepoyo/2/watch?html,css,js,output

Comment: I think this is more generic way to do this.

Comment: Neeraj, the code is a bit complex for me, but I'll check it out.